# Curl not able to get response in same server

Tags: php, web-services, curl, yii

I am using curl in my application.

My function in `DefaultController`:

```
public function actionWebServices()
{

    $data = array("account" => "1234", "dob" => "30051987", "site" => "mytestsite.com");
    $fields='';
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
        {
            $fields .= $key . '/' . $value . '/';
        }
    rtrim($fields, '&');

    $u='admin';
    $p='admin123';
    $url='localhost:83/Working-copy/mysite/ServiceTypeMaster/Test';

     $ch = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);  
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);  
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);    
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $u.':'.$p);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

     session_write_close();

     $result = curl_exec($ch);

     curl_close($ch);

     session_start();

     return $result;

}
```

In `serviceTypeMasterController`:

```
public function actionTest()
{
    echo "test";
}
```

I am calling URL of `localhost` in curl URL. but curl doesn't give any response. It only gives me only `Response Doesn't contain any data`.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, that response is if the page/service does not exist.  Are you sure you're running your server on port 83 (and not on default 80) and that the url resolves to your actionTest (instead of test) method?

Comment: yes i am running on port 83. there is issue with actionRules. my method is in authenticated user area.when i put actionTest in public it called. but i don't know how to allow authenticated  user to access protected methods in curl?